# Having a link appear after the 4th paragraph on an HTML page in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am in a JavaScript/Jquery class and for my current assignment I need to insert a back to top link after the 4th paragraph within an article. I have seem that this is a way to select a specific paragraph:

```
$("p").eq(1).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

I need to figure out how to use that with the existing Jquery:

```
  // Add "back to top" links.
  $('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter('article.chapter p');
  $('<a id="top"></a>').prependTo('body');
```

My thought was to do this:

```
  // Add "back to top" links.
  $('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter("article.chapter p").eq(3).
  $('<a id="top"></a>').prependTo('body');
```

That is not working and I just learned about this technique earlier today. What is the best way to do this.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Lisa Hergert's Assignment 6-->

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flatland</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="05.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="complete.js"></script>
    <script src="prep.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="container">
      <h1 id="f-title">Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions</h1>
      <p id="f-author">by Edwin A. Abbott</p>
      <h2>Part 1, Section 3</h2>
      <h3 id="f-subtitle">Concerning the Inhabitants of Flatland</h3>
      <p id="excerpt">an excerpt</p>

      <article class="chapter">
        <p class="square">Our Professional Men and Gentlemen are Squares (to which class I myself belong) and Five-Sided Figures or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon">Pentagons</a>.</p>

        <p class="nobility hexagon">Next above these come the Nobility, of whom there are several degrees, beginning at Six-Sided Figures, or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon">Hexagons</a>, and from thence rising in the number of their sides till they receive the honourable title of <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon">Polygonal</a>, or many-Sided. Finally when the number of the sides becomes so numerous, and the sides themselves so small, that the figure cannot be distinguished from a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle">circle</a>, he is included in the Circular or Priestly order; and this is the highest class of all.</p>

        <p><span class="pull-quote">It is a Law of Nature <span class="drop">with us</span> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father</span>, so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

        <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

        <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span> Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic, and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

        <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

        <p>How admirable is the Law of Compensation! <span class="footnote">And how perfect a proof of the natural fitness and, I may almost say, the divine origin of the aristocratic constitution of the States of Flatland!</span> By a judicious use of this Law of Nature, the Polygons and Circles are almost always able to stifle sedition in its very cradle, taking advantage of the irrepressible and boundless hopefulness of the human mind.&hellip;</p>

        <p>Then the wretched rabble of the Isosceles, planless and leaderless, are ether transfixed without resistance by the small body of their brethren whom the Chief Circle keeps in pay for emergencies of this kind; or else more often, by means of jealousies and suspicious skillfully fomented among them by the Circular party, they are stirred to mutual warfare, and perish by one another's angles. No less than one hundred and twenty rebellions are recorded in our annals, besides minor outbreaks numbered at two hundred and thirty-five; and they have all ended thus.</p>
      </article>
      <footer id="footer">
        <p>Read the <a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20050208012252/http://www.ibiblio.org/eldritch/eaa/FL.HTM">complete text of <i>Flatland</i></a>.</p>
      </footer>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also need to bold the author's name when clicking on it and then remove that bold when I click it again.

This is what I have, only half of it works:

```
  //  Clicking on authors name makes it bold
  $("#f-author").one ("click", function() {
    $(this).wrap("<b id = 'bold'></b>");
  });

  $("#bold").one ("dblclick", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Thank you.

One thing that is confusing the hell out of me, I need to add the class "inhabitants" to all the paragraphs in the chapter section without using the addClass() call. I have looked at several options, the one that worked the best, but made messy html was to wrap all the paragraphs with a new paragraph element with that class on that. I don't know what else to use for this, because some of the paragraphs already have a class and those need to be persevered.

Comment: Try using the [`:eq` *selector*](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead of the [`eq()` *method*](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):  `.insertAfter("article.chapter p:eq(3)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding the "Back To Top" link(s):

If you need it after the 4th paragraph, and every paragraph thereafter, use [the `:gt()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
insertAfter('article.chapter p:gt(2)');
```

```js
$('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter('article.chapter p:gt(2)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="chapter">
  <p class="square">Our Professional Men and Gentlemen are Squares (to which class I myself belong) and Five-Sided Figures or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon">Pentagons</a>.</p>

  <p class="nobility hexagon">Next above these come the Nobility, of whom there are several degrees, beginning at Six-Sided Figures, or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon">Hexagons</a>, and from thence rising in the number of their sides till they receive the honourable
    title of <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon">Polygonal</a>, or many-Sided. Finally when the number of the sides becomes so numerous, and the sides themselves so small, that the figure cannot be distinguished from a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle">circle</a>,
    he is included in the Circular or Priestly order; and this is the highest class of all.</p>

  <p><span class="pull-quote">It is a Law of Nature <span class="drop">with us</span> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father</span>, so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development
    and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

  <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of
    Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

  <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span>    Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic,
    and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

  <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social
    Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

  <p>How admirable is the Law of Compensation! <span class="footnote">And how perfect a proof of the natural fitness and, I may almost say, the divine origin of the aristocratic constitution of the States of Flatland!</span> By a judicious use of this Law
    of Nature, the Polygons and Circles are almost always able to stifle sedition in its very cradle, taking advantage of the irrepressible and boundless hopefulness of the human mind.&hellip;</p>

  <p>Then the wretched rabble of the Isosceles, planless and leaderless, are ether transfixed without resistance by the small body of their brethren whom the Chief Circle keeps in pay for emergencies of this kind; or else more often, by means of jealousies
    and suspicious skillfully fomented among them by the Circular party, they are stirred to mutual warfare, and perish by one another's angles. No less than one hundred and twenty rebellions are recorded in our annals, besides minor outbreaks numbered
    at two hundred and thirty-five; and they have all ended thus.</p>
</article>
```

---

If you need it after every 4th paragraph, use [the `:nth-child()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
insertAfter('article.chapter p:nth-child(4n)');
```

```js
$('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter('article.chapter p:nth-child(4n)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="chapter">
  <p class="square">Our Professional Men and Gentlemen are Squares (to which class I myself belong) and Five-Sided Figures or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon">Pentagons</a>.</p>

  <p class="nobility hexagon">Next above these come the Nobility, of whom there are several degrees, beginning at Six-Sided Figures, or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon">Hexagons</a>, and from thence rising in the number of their sides till they receive the honourable
    title of <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon">Polygonal</a>, or many-Sided. Finally when the number of the sides becomes so numerous, and the sides themselves so small, that the figure cannot be distinguished from a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle">circle</a>,
    he is included in the Circular or Priestly order; and this is the highest class of all.</p>

  <p><span class="pull-quote">It is a Law of Nature <span class="drop">with us</span> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father</span>, so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development
    and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

  <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of
    Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

  <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span>    Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic,
    and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

  <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social
    Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

  <p>How admirable is the Law of Compensation! <span class="footnote">And how perfect a proof of the natural fitness and, I may almost say, the divine origin of the aristocratic constitution of the States of Flatland!</span> By a judicious use of this Law
    of Nature, the Polygons and Circles are almost always able to stifle sedition in its very cradle, taking advantage of the irrepressible and boundless hopefulness of the human mind.&hellip;</p>

  <p>Then the wretched rabble of the Isosceles, planless and leaderless, are ether transfixed without resistance by the small body of their brethren whom the Chief Circle keeps in pay for emergencies of this kind; or else more often, by means of jealousies
    and suspicious skillfully fomented among them by the Circular party, they are stirred to mutual warfare, and perish by one another's angles. No less than one hundred and twenty rebellions are recorded in our annals, besides minor outbreaks numbered
    at two hundred and thirty-five; and they have all ended thus.</p>
</article>
```

---

If you need it after the 4th paragraph, and only the 4th paragraph, use [the `:eq()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
insertAfter('article.chapter p:eq(3)');
```

```js
$('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter('article.chapter p:eq(3)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="chapter">
  <p class="square">Our Professional Men and Gentlemen are Squares (to which class I myself belong) and Five-Sided Figures or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon">Pentagons</a>.</p>

  <p class="nobility hexagon">Next above these come the Nobility, of whom there are several degrees, beginning at Six-Sided Figures, or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon">Hexagons</a>, and from thence rising in the number of their sides till they receive the honourable
    title of <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon">Polygonal</a>, or many-Sided. Finally when the number of the sides becomes so numerous, and the sides themselves so small, that the figure cannot be distinguished from a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle">circle</a>,
    he is included in the Circular or Priestly order; and this is the highest class of all.</p>

  <p><span class="pull-quote">It is a Law of Nature <span class="drop">with us</span> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father</span>, so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development
    and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

  <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of
    Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

  <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span>    Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic,
    and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

  <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social
    Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

  <p>How admirable is the Law of Compensation! <span class="footnote">And how perfect a proof of the natural fitness and, I may almost say, the divine origin of the aristocratic constitution of the States of Flatland!</span> By a judicious use of this Law
    of Nature, the Polygons and Circles are almost always able to stifle sedition in its very cradle, taking advantage of the irrepressible and boundless hopefulness of the human mind.&hellip;</p>

  <p>Then the wretched rabble of the Isosceles, planless and leaderless, are ether transfixed without resistance by the small body of their brethren whom the Chief Circle keeps in pay for emergencies of this kind; or else more often, by means of jealousies
    and suspicious skillfully fomented among them by the Circular party, they are stirred to mutual warfare, and perish by one another's angles. No less than one hundred and twenty rebellions are recorded in our annals, besides minor outbreaks numbered
    at two hundred and thirty-five; and they have all ended thus.</p>
</article>
```

---

### Bolding the author's name:

Add a CSS class for bold text, and use jQuery's `toggleClass()` to toggle it on/off with each click, thus adding/removing the bold:

```
.bolded-text { font-weight: bold; }
```

```
$(this).toggleClass("bolded-text");
```

```js
$("#f-author").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("bolded-text");
});
```

```css
.bolded-text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="f-title">Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions</h1>
<p id="f-author">by Edwin A. Abbott</p>
<h2>Part 1, Section 3</h2>
<h3 id="f-subtitle">Concerning the Inhabitants of Flatland</h3>
```

Comment: This would work but it needs the link after all paragraphs after the 4th

Comment: At least this is what the requirement says: 
1. Alter the code that introduces the back to top links so that the links only appear after the fourth paragraph.

Comment: @Lisa I've edited my answer to use `:gt` instead, should work as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `insertAfter("article.chapter p:eq(3)")` so that the fourth `p` is selected. Notice the pseudo class `:eq(3)` inside `insertAfter` which will select only the fourth paragraph from the list of paragraphs.

Also, if you want the link after each four paragraph then you need to loop through the paragraphs and set the `:eq()` dynamically.

```js
var i = 4;
var elem = $('article.chapter p');
$('<a id="top"></a>').prependTo('body');
while(i<=elem.length){
  $('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter("article.chapter p:eq("+(i-1)+")");
  i+=4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="chapter">
        <p class="square">Our Professional Men and Gentlemen are Squares (to which class I myself belong) and Five-Sided Figures or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon">Pentagons</a>.</p>

        <p class="nobility hexagon">Next above these come the Nobility, of whom there are several degrees, beginning at Six-Sided Figures, or <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon">Hexagons</a>, and from thence rising in the number of their sides till they receive the honourable title of <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon">Polygonal</a>, or many-Sided. Finally when the number of the sides becomes so numerous, and the sides themselves so small, that the figure cannot be distinguished from a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle">circle</a>, he is included in the Circular or Priestly order; and this is the highest class of all.</p>

        <p><span class="pull-quote">It is a Law of Nature <span class="drop">with us</span> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father</span>, so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

        <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

        <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span> Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic, and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

        <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

        <p>How admirable is the Law of Compensation! <span class="footnote">And how perfect a proof of the natural fitness and, I may almost say, the divine origin of the aristocratic constitution of the States of Flatland!</span> By a judicious use of this Law of Nature, the Polygons and Circles are almost always able to stifle sedition in its very cradle, taking advantage of the irrepressible and boundless hopefulness of the human mind.&hellip;</p>

        <p>Then the wretched rabble of the Isosceles, planless and leaderless, are ether transfixed without resistance by the small body of their brethren whom the Chief Circle keeps in pay for emergencies of this kind; or else more often, by means of jealousies and suspicious skillfully fomented among them by the Circular party, they are stirred to mutual warfare, and perish by one another's angles. No less than one hundred and twenty rebellions are recorded in our annals, besides minor outbreaks numbered at two hundred and thirty-five; and they have all ended thus.</p>
        <p> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

        <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

        <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span> Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic, and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

        <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

<p> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

        <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

        <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span> Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic, and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

        <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

<p> that a male child shall have <strong>one more side</strong> than his father so that each generation shall rise (as a rule) one step in the scale of development and nobility. Thus the son of a Square is a Pentagon; the son of a Pentagon, a Hexagon; and so on.</p>

        <p>But this rule applies not always to the Tradesman, and still less often to the Soldiers, and to the Workmen; who indeed can hardly be said to deserve the name of human Figures, since they have not all their sides equal. With them therefore the Law of Nature does not hold; and the son of an Isosceles (i.e. a Triangle with two sides equal) remains Isosceles still. Nevertheless, all hope is not such out, even from the Isosceles, that his posterity may ultimately rise above his degraded condition.&hellip;</p>

        <p>Rarely&mdash;in proportion to the vast numbers of Isosceles births&mdash;is a genuine and certifiable Equal-Sided Triangle produced from Isosceles parents. <span class="footnote">"What need of a certificate?" a Spaceland critic may ask: "Is not the procreation of a Square Son a certificate from Nature herself, proving the Equal-sidedness of the Father?" I reply that no Lady of any position will marry an uncertified Triangle. Square offspring has sometimes resulted from a slightly Irregular Triangle; but in almost every such case the Irregularity of the first generation is visited on the third; which either fails to attain the Pentagonal rank, or relapses to the Triangular.</span> Such a birth requires, as its antecedents, not only a series of carefully arranged intermarriages, but also a long-continued exercise of frugality and self-control on the part of the would-be ancestors of the coming Equilateral, and a patient, systematic, and continuous development of the Isosceles intellect through many generations.</p>

        <p><span class="pull-quote">The birth  of a True Equilateral Triangle from Isosceles parents is the subject of rejoicing in our country <span class="drop">for many furlongs round</span>.</span> After a strict examination conducted by the Sanitary and Social Board, the infant, if certified as Regular, is with solemn ceremonial admitted into the class of Equilaterals. He is then immediately taken from his proud yet sorrowing parents and adopted by some childless Equilateral. <span class="footnote">The Equilateral is bound by oath never to permit the child henceforth to enter his former home or so much as to look upon his relations again, for fear lest the freshly developed organism may, by force of unconscious imitation, fall back again into his hereditary level.</span></p>

      </article>
      <footer id="footer">
        <p>Read the <a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20050208012252/http://www.ibiblio.org/eldritch/eaa/FL.HTM">complete text of <i>Flatland</i></a>.</p>
      </footer>
```

Comment: What if I need the links after all paragraphs after the fourth one?

Comment: Slight problem, you loop is doing this:

<a href="file:///C:/Users/outof/Documents/CSD%20122/Assignment6_files/index.html#top#top#top#top#top">back to top</a>

Comment: @Lisa what is it doing?

Comment: The link is getting messed up with extra #top

Comment: You might have more JQuery there that is not behaving well with the loop otherwise see the working snippet above that works fine

Comment: I did pull the adding the top class out of the loop

Comment: What do you mean by that @Lisa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172283/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-lisa).

Comment: This: 
// Add "back to top" links.
 var i = 3;
 var elem = $('article.chapter p');
 while(i <= elem.length){
  $('<a href="#top">back to top</a>').insertAfter("article.chapter p:eq("+ i +")");
  i+=1;
 }
 
 $('<a id="top"></a>').prependTo('body');